# making the pointlabels behind the highlighter in jqplot

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I'm trying to make a highlighter on a simple line graph, and no matter what I do, the pointlabel keeps being above the tooltip and hides the content

anyone has an idea of how to make it happen?

Answer (score 2):

You must modify the jqplot css file:

```css
.jqplot-highlighter-tooltip, .jqplot-canvasOverlay-tooltip {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: rgba(208,208,208,0.5);
    padding: 1px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Adding a **z-index** greater than the .jqplot-point-label has, must solve the problem.

Comment: in case it doesn't, try adding `z-index: 100 !important;`